# why a deformation retract mapping to a single point would imply path connectedness

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology

I have just started doing some self study about algebraic topology. I read wikipedia and it said "having a single point as a deformation retract of a space X would imply that X is path connected". I couldn't figure out why. Could anyone give me a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 2):

Let $H:X\times [0, 1]\to X$ be a deformation retraction to a single point $x_0\in X$, with $H(x, 0) = x$ and $H(x, 1) = x_0$. Say we have two arbitrary points $p, q\in X$. Let $\gamma_1, \gamma_2:[0,1]\to X$ given by $$
\gamma_1(t) = H(p, t)\\
\gamma_2(t) = H(q, 1-t)
$$
Concatenating $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ gives a path from $p$ to $q$.

In more words, and less formulas: The deformation retraction to the point $x_0\in X$ gives a path in $X$ from any point to $x_0$. So to make a path from $p\in X$ to $q\in X$, take the deformation-retraction-induced path from $p$ to $x_0$, then go backwards along the induced path from $q$ to $x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $H:X\times\mathbb I\to X$ be a deformation retract of space $X$ to a single point $c\in X$ so that $H(-,0)=\mathsf{id}_X$ and $H(-,1)$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto c$.

Then for a fixed $x\in X$ the map $\mathbb I\to X$ prescribed by $t\mapsto H(x,t)$ is continuous hence can be recognized as a path from $x$ to $c$.

Almost similarly (going backwards) for another fixed $x'\in X$ we can construct a path from $c$ to $x'$.

Combining this we find a path from $x$ to $x'$.

This is possible for every pair $(x,x')$.

Comment: Thank you very much It is really helpful.